# How did the usage of the word "pretty" become synonymous with the word "really"?

Tags: colloquialisms

When and how did Americans come to accept and widely interchange the word "pretty" for "really"?  (ex. "It was a pretty big tornado".  "She had a pretty bad headache".)

Comment: Etymonline says [this sense has existed since the 15th C](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pretty), so it's not an American thing; it's been around since Middle English: *Meaning "not a few, considerable" is from late 15c. With a sense of "moderately," qualifying adjectives and adverbs, since 1560s.*.